# Apple bluetooth keyboard Device added successfully but failed to connect

Tags: keyboard, bluetooth

Up until this morning I had my Apple bluetooth keyboard auto connecting when I boot up. Now, for some strange reason (an update?, though don't recall updating anything) it doesn't auto connect, and when I try and manually connect I get the following error message

```
Device added successfully but failed to connect
```

Running latest ubuntu-mate 16.04. Can anyone suggest troubleshooting steps?